# Dual extruder does support/secondary extruder stay hot during entire print?

Tags: reprap, dual-nozzle

The hot end set-up for my printer consist of 2 Titan Aero extruders. The printer relies on Reprap firmware and a Duet 3 controller board. When I finish setting everything up, my primary extruder will use ABS and my secondary extruder will uses HIPS.

If the model I am printing only has supports near its base, once the supports have been completely printed, will the secondary extruder remain hot/at its printing temperature setpoint until the entire print finishes?  Or has this been worked out.

Even more specifically say the HIPS extruder isn't needed for several hours during a print. Will it cool down and begin heating up when its needed or just slightly ahead of time?

I feel like the HIPS filament left over in the extruder would be ruined after this and likely to clog going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slicer Cura has a standby temperature that is used when the hotend is not in use. Furthermore, you can write your own filament/hotend change scripts to do whatever you want. You can even do a full cool down of a hotend and full warmup when it is needed again. You can also always edit your G-code file after slicing, use a standby temperature for the beginning of the print where supports are used, and manually change the G-code at the last change to disable the HIPS extruder.

Comment: I’m using BCN3D’s fork of Cura, for a Sigma printer, and it is very smart about standby temperature on the idle head- it starts heating the head from standby temp while the other head is finishing up the layer, so you aren’t waiting for it to heat at the tool change. 
Does anyone know if that look ahead functionality is something a user could program in stock Cura, or Prusaslicer? The custom tool change G-Code would fire off too late. Not happy with current slicer, the gap fill seems broken.

Comment: I use Cura 4.9.  Is Cura set-up to begin heating the stand-by extruder once the printer starts on a layer requiring the secondary extruder?

Comment: @ChinchillaWafers what do you mean the custom Gcode would fire too late?

Comment: “Fire too late” I should have said the tool change g-code script doesn’t get executed until the previous extruder is done with its part of the layer, so if you’re at standby temp, say 150C, and the tool change gcode tells the second extruder to heat up to printing temp, the printer is sitting there idle while it heats. So not “too late”, but it’s making bad use of the time, by not starting the heating cycle ahead of the tool change.

Comment: The BCN version of Cura is set up to do the heating from standby on the idle head in the middle of the layer, it knows how long it takes to heat, and it’s ready by the time for the tool change. It’s slick. It also shuts the extruder down if the print is done with that material. Just wondering if that behavior is possible to program in stock Cura, and take advantage of its slicing improvements, or if I’m stuck with the BCN version, for its good management of standby temp behavior.